# Problem in Deleting Duplicate Rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates, mariadb

I want to delete duplicate rows from my table. If I run only the subquery it works fine. But when I add the delete clause MySQL is giving me errors.

**Here is my code:**

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE   (SELECT timestamp, 
             clinician_email, 
             clinician_uid,
             source
             
      FROM `test`
      WHERE cast(timestamp as date)  <= cast(CURRENT_DATE()as date) 
            and cast(timestamp as date) >= cast(CURRENT_DATE() -10 as date) 
      GROUP by timestamp, clinician_email, clinician_uid,source
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     
     )
```

**Error:**

MySQL said: Documentation

#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Incorrect logic. You must use multiple-table delete: `DELETE t1 FROM test t1 NATURAL JOIN ({subquery}) t2;`. But there is a problem - you'll delete ALL duplicates, not "all except one".

Comment: Use CTE and row_number() for serialyze data

Comment: @Akina thanks a lot it worked. Can you explain to me why  I have to do natural join? Because my query worked fine in the SQL server.

Comment: *why I have to do natural join?* You do not have to use NATURAL JOIN, you may use common INNER JOIN with ON or USING clause. But NATURAL JOIN allows do not list all column names which should be used for joining, it performs join by all columns which have the same names. So your 4 columns selected in the subquery are joined to the same columns in the table copy which will be used for deletion.